# Laravel 5 relationship belongsTo not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

First of all what I want to achieve it's quite simple : I want to use relationship belongsTo from Laravel 5 to get a value from another table. Like so

```
<?= $email->contact->first_name; ?>
```

But this is not working at all, instead, I get this error : Trying to get property of non-object. But when I do print_r($email) it shows me that $email is actually an object...So I really don't understand now.

This is (a part of) what I have in my Controller :

```
$emails = Email::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->take(6)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This is what I have in my view :

```
foreach($emails as $key => $email) {
     echo $email->contact->first_name; ?>
}
```

This is my model email

```
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Contact', 'contact_id');
}
```

As you can see, I am using a second parameter inside belongsTo method, which is 'contact_id' because I don't want to use 'user_id' as the foreign key.

EDIT:

This is my output of print_r($email) :

```
App\Email Object ( [connection:protected] => [table:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 88 [user_id] => 1 [group_id] => 1 [contact_id] => 79 [reminder_id] => 31 [subject] => Test task #3 [view] => 0 [view_hash] => $2y$10$NZ3B.UUqtRRl2opH5UwXOeRNeRROeZGdid6Crs4ShT1VptbZJS.iu [content] => blablabla
```

EDIT 2 :

This is my output of print_r($email->contact) :

```
App\Contact Object ( [fillable:protected] => Array ( [0] => title [1] => content ) [table:protected] => contacts [connection:protected] => [primaryKey:protected] => id [perPage:protected] => 15 [incrementing] => 1 [timestamps] => 1 [attributes:protected] => Array ( [id] => 86 [user_id] => 1 [group_id] => 1 [first_name] => Matthieu [last_name] => Boistoule [email] => m.boistoule@gmail.com [phone] => [company] => [title] => [website] => [industry] => [address] => [city] => [country] => [province] => [postal_code] => [lead_source] => [notes] => [created_at] => 2015-06-04 12:13:00 [updated_at] => 2015-06-04 12:13:00 ) [original:protected] => Array ( [id] => 86 [user_id] => 1 [group_id] => 1 [first_name] => Matthieu [last_name] => Boistoule [email] => m.boistoule@gmail.com [phone] => [company] => [title] => [website] => [industry] => [address] => [city] => [country] => [province] => [postal_code] => [lead_source] => [notes] => [created_at] => 2015-06-04 12:13:00 [updated_at] => 2015-06-04 12:13:00 ) [relations:protected] => Array ( ) [hidden:protected] => Array ( ) [visible:protected] => Array ( ) [appends:protected] => Array ( ) [guarded:protected] => Array ( [0] => * ) [dates:protected] => Array ( ) [casts:protected] => Array ( ) [touches:protected] => Array ( ) [observables:protected] => Array ( ) [with:protected] => Array ( ) [morphClass:protected] => [exists] => 1 )
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($email)` ? Thus, you don't need the second parameter, its the default one already, as it belongs to `App\Contact`, Eloquent already assumes it as `contact_id`.

Comment: it is quite big, so I will edit my answer and add it in there!

Comment: as i see from your dump, it's not referencing `contact` thats why you are getting not an object error. Your query should work actually, but anyway, try this too  `Email::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->with('contact')->take(6)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: Hello, I tried it and it's still not working. However, I am using the same technic from another variable in my controller and it's working. I really don't know why $email->contact is not working properly. I tried to print_r($email->contact) and it's working, I get the app\contact object but when I echo out $email->contact->first_name it says : trying to get property of non-object...I'm still on this issue -_-

Comment: what about the output of `print_r($email->contact) ` then?

Comment: I edited so you can see the output of it!

Comment: is there an email without a contact relation? Maybe you should check it with `if (count($email->contact)){ echo $email->contact->first_name; }`

Comment: Hello, finally I found something. When I did var_dump($email->contact), there was 5 "null" before everything. So I decided to delete everything in my DB and put back some temporary rows and it worked. Thank you for your time, Burak!